# Typesetting of per-degree

Tags: notation

What is the best (most accepted) way to typeset something like $5$ per (angular, not temperature) degree (in $\LaTeX$)?
I came up with the following options (using `^\circ` for the $^\circ$ symbol):

- $5 \frac{1}{^\circ}$
- $5/^\circ$ (eventually with a $1$ before the '$/$'.)
- $5{}^{\circ ^{-1}}$ (my favorite so far)
- $5{}^\circ{}^{-1}$
- $5^{/\circ}$ (Thanks to Michael Hardy)

and the code to produce that output:

- `5 \frac{1}{^\circ}`
- `5/^\circ`
- `5{}^{\circ ^{-1}}`
- `5{}^\circ{}^{-1}`
- `5^{/\circ}` (no `^` before `\circ`)

Note that I'm not asking this on the Latex forum, because the problem is that I don't know what it should look like. After that, formatting shouldn't be a problem.
PS: What is an appropriate tag for this question?

Comment: Why not “5 per degree”?

Comment: @MJD: Excessively readable.

Comment: @MJD, Hadn't really thought of that yet :) However, I like to put the units within the mathematical expression, not outside of it. Also, I might have a list of 'per degree' values in a table, and then that wouldn't be a solution.

Comment: You missed $\displaystyle 5^{/\circ}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, that's like $5^{\frac 12}$ as inverse of $5^2$ (which seems counterintuitive), but does look pretty good.

Comment: The standard SI supplemental unit for angle is the radian; you could write $286.479 \text{ rad}^{-1}$, which would be completely standard and unexceptionable, but which seems to obscure the essence of what you are trying to communicate..

Comment: @MJD, I'm writing a report and all our measurements and data processing are done in degrees, so it would be weird to use radians for this purpose only. In fact, we had a remark in our draft that we did use radians once, so I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: @Ragnar : But $5^\circ$ is like $5^3$ as $5\cdot3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen $5 \text{ deg}^{-1}$ and like that.

Answer (score 0):

"Per degree" (perhaps better use radians if talking math?) isn't really an unit, it is a dimensionless ratio. So, to be really rigurous, there is no unit. In any case, it is better to use the general [ISO guidelines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_31-0) for readability.

Comment: Are you sure that the ISO guidelines treat this case?  I consulted the [Guide for the Use of the International System of Units (SI)](http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/sp811.pdf), which is quite extensive, but saw nothing relevant. And although degrees and radians are technically dimensionless, it is quite common, and standard, to state them explicitly where doing so improves clarity; this is why radians are an SI supplementary unit.

Comment: No, ISO doesn't treat this case.